# Pagination in while loop with php

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I'm newbee about php,trying to learn.
I've search other topic about while loop pagination but not satisfied.

I have 70 user records in my database,wants to list them with html table. I'm showing all records with this code. How can i make simple pagination with these codes? Please help me.

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Surname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Password</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    <?php
    $q = "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY uid ASC";
    $r = mysqli_query($dbc,$q);

    while($userlist = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)){ ?>
      <tr>
          <td><?php echo $userlist['uid']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $userlist['name']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $userlist['surname']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $userlist['email']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $userlist['password']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $userlist['date']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $userlist['gender']; ?></td>
      </tr>
      <?php } ?>     
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Use the LIMIT clause and maintain the number to show and starting record in your page.

Comment: You need a `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` in the query. The `OFFSET` is dynamically built based on the current page and what the `LIMIT` is set to. So `LIMIT 3` gives 3 items per page. Then you need `OFFSET` to be `($pageNumber-1)*3`, making it `OFFSET ($pageNumber-1)*3` in the query. Remember to **validate** page numbers, as they ususally can be manipulated by users - use a prepared statement with placeholders.

Comment: As an advice: Don't store passwords in plaintext, also don't show passwords of all users to somebody.

Comment: how can i make it possible ? 
$q = "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY uid ASC LIMIT 10";
its gives me 10 records, how can i show other records with a button(a pagination) and what is OFFSET? how can i use that? please explain with an example

Comment: That's what the `OFFSET` is for, which I already gave an example for. If you do `LIMIT 10, OFFSET 20`, you get "page 3".

Comment: $inserusernamehere, i'm using this in my admin dashboard. maybe i'll encrypte passwords

Comment: @NihatÖzyedi ***maybe*** you'll encrypt passwords?! Treat your users with the security they deserve; ALWAYS hash (not encrypt, hash!) passwords and other sensitive information, and **never** display it to anyone. Actively displaying and insecurely storing it like this is a big security issue, and if I knew a website is doing that, I'd *never* use it and actively warn others against using it. Treat information from your users with respect and safety! What if your account is hacked, then someone can access the adminpanel and see the password of EVERYONE! See http://php.net/password_hash

Comment: @Qirel i've tried and i understand this method. Should i create while loops for every pagination buttons with these codes to change queries?
For example: $q = "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY uid ASC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10";(first list)
$q = "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY uid ASC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 20";(second list)
$q = "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY uid ASC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 30";(third list).....
lot of records and while loops. any shotcut ? :D

Comment: You create a dynamic page. `index.php?page=1` or `index.php?page=3` (example). Then you can use `$_GET['page']` as your `$pageNumber` in the example I had above. That should be enough to enable you to figure it out. But like I said, **please, please, please** read up on password-security. You're not doing anyone any favors by "maybe" hashing it, or even worse, displaying the unhashed passwords anywhere at all.. Security is a very important topic, please don't neglect it, or even worse "fix it later" - fix it now!

Comment: @Qirel dont harsh on me pls. I'm trying to learn about this discipline. Of course i'll not show this all over the planet. Showing cos' i'm changing this another query and adding new one. Edit: Reading your link now

Comment: I'm not trying to be rude, but security is most likely the last thing a beginner thinks of, and it's a very, very important topic, which cannot be ignored. Never. I've seen it far too many times that once informed about these important issues, that the user says they'll "do it later", and it never gets done. Like it has been said already, passwords are sacred and holy - store them safely, and never ever show it anywhere!

Answer (score 2):

The follow provide very simple pagination as a starting point. You will need to supply formatting for the pagination and such.

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Surname</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Password</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<?php
    $q = "SELECT count(*) as `numrows` FROM `users` ORDER BY `uid` ASC";
    $c = mysqli_query($dbc,$q);
    if($c) {
        if($t = mysqli_fetch_assoc($c)) {
            $numrows = $t['numrows'];
        }
    }

    $numrows = 0;
    $rowsperpage = 10;
    $currpage = isset($_REQUEST['currpageno']) && $_REQUEST['currpageno'] != 0 ? $_REQUEST['currpageno'] : 1;
    $numpages = ceil($numrows / $rowsperpage);
    $startrow = ($currpage - 1) * $rowsperpage;
    if($startrow > $numrows) {
        $startrow = $numrows - $rowsperpage;
    }
    if($startrow < 0) {
        $startrow = 0;
    }


    $q = "SELECT * FROM `users` ORDER BY `uid` ASC LIMIT ".$startrow.",".$rowsperpage.";";
    $r = mysqli_query($dbc,$q);

    while($userlist = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)){ 
?>
        <tr>
                <td><?php echo $userlist['uid']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $userlist['name']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $userlist['surname']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $userlist['email']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $userlist['password']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $userlist['date']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $userlist['gender']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>       
    </tbody>
</table>
<div id='pagination'>
<?php
    for($pgno = 1;$pgno <= $numpages;$pgno++) {
        echo "<a class='' href='?currpageno=".$pgno."'>".$pgno."</a>";
    }
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Why the down vote? Also, why down vote without leaving a comment about the reason?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in  "  gives this error message. "}" is missing somewhere i guess. trying in somewhere in codes.
what is currpageno? you requesting this as a variable. Is it means dynamic web adress like index.php?page=7 ?

Edit: I'm using bootstrap pagination. Using your code like;
<nav aria-label="Page navigation">
    <ul class="pagination">
    <?php
    for($pgno = 1;$pgno <= $numpages;$pgno++) {
        echo "<li><a href='?currpageno=".$pgno."'>".$pgno."</a></li>";
    }
    ?></ul></nav>

Comment: Since it wasn't in the code you provided, nor was any indication that was the case, I supplied a very simplified pagination as an example. Focus instead on the sql statement and how it limits the rows in the query based on the page to be shown.

Comment: i'm trying to focus but not understanding this "request currpagno ", and "}" is still missing. thanks already

Comment: I fixed the missing }. About the $_REQUEST['currpageno']. That's how the code knows which page of results to display. The page number is in the <a> tags for page number.

Comment: Sloan, unfortunately its not working for me :( trying this code but not seeing any pagination number. also i'm trying <a href="?currpageno=1">1</a>
<a href="?currpageno=2">2</a>

but this links not working

Comment: Just hit the page with ?currpageno=2 at the end of the url (replace ? with & if there are other parameters)

Comment: It's not working for me. I'm using $_GET array for dynamicly loading pages from database. my index page is index.php?page=1

Edit: I've tried ?currpageno=2 and &currpageno=2 also didnt work for me
index.php?page=1?currpageno=2 not working
index.php?page=1&currpageno=2 not working

Comment: in the last div, $numpages will be 0, in this code.